# Appropiate statistical test for the following design

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, experiment-design

Experiment is designed as it follows:
9 different pH treatments (controlled), in each treatments 40 marked individuals (randomly chosen from a larger population). Measurements (length, weight, etc.) were performed on the same day on every marked individual from each pH treatment over several time points.
Research question is: Is the variable response changing with pH?

How do I approach this? What statistical test would be appropriate? Point in any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be modeled by regression, with some considerations relating to the correlations within individuals over time and the correlations among outcome measures within individuals.

Start by considering a single outcome measure. You fit the outcome as a function of your controlled independent variable (the pH treatment), as a function of time, and with an interaction between treatment and time that allows for differences in trajectories over time depending on pH. You should allow for some flexibility in the association of the outcome with both pH and time, for example with regression splines. Section 2.4 of Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#sec-relax.linear) (RMS) discusses that aspect of the modeling.

Even for a single outcome measure, you would also have to take the correlations among measurements within an individual into account. [Chapter 7 of RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html) discusses ways to do that, with an emphasis on generalized least squares. Such data are also often analyzed with mixed models, treating the individuals as contributing random effects to baseline values (intercepts) or associations with treatment or time.

The multiple outcome measurements (length, weight) are likely to be correlated within a single individual, which should be taken into account. There are several ways to handle such correlated outcome, with different strengths and weaknesses.  You need to consider your goals and your understanding of the subject matter to decide how to proceed.

You could, for example, combine each set of outcome measurements into a single value (for example, via principal-component analysis, or some other method established in your field of study). You could build separate models for each outcome and combine them in a way that takes the correlations into account. Or you could devise a model of all outcome measurements together.

As an example of the latter, if you have complete data on all individuals and all measurements at all time points, you could consider the classic repeated-measures model described in Section 3 of Fox and Weisberg's [Appendix on Multivariate Linear Models](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Multivariate-Linear-Models.pdf). You put all data for each individual into a single row, with all of the measurements as responses in a multivariate linear model. Then you obtain results from the model by specifying the structure of the intra-individual design to post-modeling tests.

Technically, what you have is multivariate (multiple-outcome) longitudinal (measured on the same individuals) data. With a set of shared time points at which all individuals were measured, this could also be called "panel data." Searches on those terms should provide more details about ways to proceed (although some people use "multivariate" to mean multiple predictors rather than multiple outcomes, so you need to be careful with that term). For example, Bandyopadhyay et al. provide "A review of multivariate longitudinal data analysis" in [Statistical Methods in Medical Research 2011; 20: 299–330](https://doi.org/10.1177/0962280209340191), which discusses the strengths and weaknesses of the three general approaches outlined above and different ways to implement them.